# Llist of items that have been deleted

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey

I want to display the list of items that i have deleted so far (JAVA). I'm using database as mysql. I'm giving a button in UI on clicking it web service will called and should display the deleted entry. I tried this:

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        String a = iter.next();
            if (...) {
                 iter.remove();
            }
}
```

Comment: Tyy to keep the deleted item in a list.

Comment: you need to supply a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the removed items in a data structure like linked list which is appropriate for appending new items and you don't need to consist memory to it when you define it.

```
List<String> listOfRemovedItems = new LinkedList<>();
    Iterator iterator = originalList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String s = iterator.next().toString();
        if ("meets your condition") {
            listOfRemovedItems.add(s);
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay. I'm using delete function of hibernate for deleting entry from database. what i did is i added an flag isDeleted in DTO. that when entry is getting deleted the flag will be set to 1. But i'm not able to update the flag when the entry is deleted. Because the it is deleting the entry row. Thats y i thought not to add any table in database and just adding extra column in table so trying that but not working

Answer (score 0):

I added one extra column in table as Flag. Now when user delete it flag is to 1 otherwise it is false.